# Cleanly list all remote branches with filter

Tags: git

I'm writing a script to list all remote branch starting with the prefix 'example'.

I see `git ls-remote --heads` kind of does what I want but lists hash and then `refs/heads/<branch>`.

Is there a simple way to get all the remote branches so I can parse them into a bash array?  I can't see anything in the docs for `ls-remote`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

A quick, sloppy-ish one that strips the default HEAD:

```
lst=( $( git branch -r | grep -v '/HEAD ->' ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" "refs/heads/origin/example*"
```

#### Details

Remember that remote-tracking names are created and updated by `git fetch` (and deleted if appropriate by `git fetch --prune` or `git remote prune`), so if you're going to use your remote-tracking names—rather than using `git ls-remote` to call up the remote directly, and get its information—be sure your Git is reasonably up-to-date.

That said, the *plumbing command* `git for-each-ref` is ideal for this.<sup>1</sup>  Remote-tracking names like `origin/master` are actually *references* whose full spelling starts with `refs/remotes/`.  This goes on to include the remote name itself, such as `origin`, then another slash, and after that comes the branch name as seen on the remote: `origin's` `master` is your `refs/remotes/origin/master`, for instance.

The for-each-ref command takes a prefix, and enumerate only those branches that begin with that prefix (and a `/*` unless you put in your own `*`).  So if you meant: *only `origin/example/*`*, then:

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads/origin/example
```

iterates over exactly the right set of names.  But if you meant `origin/example*`, you need:

```
git for-each-ref "refs/heads/origin/example*"
```

Quoting the asterisk (as I did here) is required in some cases, and optional in other cases, but is always allowed and never hurts, so it's a good idea to do it always.

Now, the `git for-each-ref` command's *default output* isn't what you want, but its output is *extremely flexible*.  As a command whose entire purpose is to generate the kind of output you *do* want, it has lots of options.  The option you want here is `--format`, which takes *formatting directives*.  You probably want `--format=%(refname)` or `--format=%(refname:short)`.  Exactly which one you do want, and when, and why, is not something we can answer: you need to answer it for yourself.

Because the format directive needs parentheses, and some command line interpreters have their own meaning for parentheses, you'll probably need to quote the parentheses as well.  I did this in the example at the top.

---

<sup>1</sup>A *plumbing command* is one that is meant to be used by a script.  This contrasts with a *porcelain command*.  In Git, porcelain commands are those meant for interacting with humans.  They will often run their output through a pager (`core.pager`), colorize the output, and/or behave differently for each user depending on the user's configuration settings.  *Plumbing* commands will behave the same way every time, so that, e.g., programs that expect colored or uncolored output will get colored or uncolored output based on the command's *arguments*, not on a per-user configuration.

When writing scripts, you should usually prefer a plumbing command if one is available.  Sometimes one isn't available: for instance, there is no plumbing equivalent of `git log`.  (There should be.)  There is no plumbing `git status` but `git status` has the `--porcelain=<version>` *option*, which converts it to a plumbing command.